# Updating a layer inside SVG file with React

Tags: reactjs, svg, dom

I have a very big SVG file which is near 10k lines and I want to update some of its layers fill color via useEffect or a similar method. However I don't want to import whole file in a component and re-render every time I need to change a color.

Is there a way to update svg elements through React? I guess there are hacky ways to achieve this but I want to know what is the encouraged way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go through the SVG file for any instances where the color needs to be changed, but it would look something like this:

```
import React from "react";

const SVG = (props) => {
  return <svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill={props.fillColor} stroke-width="3" stroke={props.strokeColor} />
</svg> 
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SVG fillColor="red" strokeColor="#000000" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically you can turn your SVG into a React component and for any attributes that need to be customized, use props passed in from the parent component.